# Is there a way to handle asp.net core odata errors

Tags: asp.net-core, odata

Is there a way to handle asp.net core odata errors?

I have a model class `DimDateAvailable` with one property, a primary key of `int DateId`, and I make a call like `/data/DimDateAvailable?$select=test`.

Other calls work as expected and return what I'm after - this is a deliberate call to generate a fault, and it fails because there is no property named test on the model. The response comes back as expected, like so: `{"error":{"code":"","message":"The query specified in the URI is not valid. Could not find a property named 'test' on type 'DimDateAvailable'...` followed by a stack trace.

This response is fine when `env.IsDevelopment()` is `true` but I don't want to expose the stack trace when not in development.

I've looked at wrapping the code in the controllers' `get` method in a try-catch, but I think there's an action filter running over the results so it never gets called. On the other hand, I can't see where to inject any middleware and/or add any filters to catch errors. I suspect there might be a way to override an output formatter to achieve what I want but I can't see how.

Here's what I have at the moment:

In Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddScoped<TelemetryDbContext>();
  services.AddOData();
  services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
  if (env.IsDevelopment())
  {
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
  }

  app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
  {
    routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "data", GetEdmModel());
    routeBuilder.Select().Expand().Filter().OrderBy().MaxTop(null).Count();

    // insert special bits for e.g. custom MLE here
    routeBuilder.EnableDependencyInjection();
  });
}

private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
  var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
  builder.EntitySet<DimDateAvailable>("DimDateAvailable");
  return builder.GetEdmModel();
}
```

In TelemetryDbContext.cs:

```
public virtual DbSet<DimDateAvailable> DimDateAvailable { get; set; }
```

In DimDateAvailable.cs

```
public class DimDateAvailable
{
  [Key]
  public int DateId { get; set; }
}
```

My controller:

```
public class DimDateAvailableController : ODataController
{
  private readonly TelemetryDbContext data;

  public DimDateAvailableController(TelemetryDbContext data)
  {
    this.data = data;
  }

  [EnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.Supported, PageSize = 2000)]
  public IActionResult Get()
  {
    return Ok(this.data.DimDateAvailable.AsQueryable());
  }
}
```

This is in an asp.net core 2 web app with the Microsoft.AspNetCoreOData v7.0.1 and EntityFramework 6.2.0 packages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Investigating Ihar's suggestion lead me down the rabbit hole, and I ended up inserting an `ODataOutputFormatter` into the MVC options to intercept `ODataPayloadKind.Error` responses and reformat them.

It was interesting to see that `context.Features` held an instance of `IExceptionHandlerFeature` in `app.UseExceptionHandler()` but not in the `ODataOutputFormatter`. That lack was pretty much what prompted me to pose this question in the first place, but was solved by translating the `context.Object` in the `ODataOutputFormatter` which is something I saw done in the OData source as well. I don't know if the changes below are good practice in asp.net core or when using the AspNetCoreOData package, but they do what I want for now.

Changes to Startup.cs

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddScoped<TelemetryDbContext>();
  services.AddOData();
  services.AddMvc(options =>
  {
    options.OutputFormatters.Insert(0, new CustomODataOutputFormatter(this.Environment.IsDevelopment()));   
  });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
  if (env.IsDevelopment())
  {
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
  }

  // Added this to catch errors in my own code and return them to the client as ODataErrors
  app.UseExceptionHandler(appBuilder =>
  {
    appBuilder.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
      var error = context.Features[typeof(IExceptionHandlerFeature)] as IExceptionHandlerFeature;
      if (error?.Error != null)
      {
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

        var response = error.Error.CreateODataError(!env.IsDevelopment());
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response));
      }

      // when no error, do next.
      else await next();
    });
  });

  app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
  {
    routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "data", GetEdmModel());
    routeBuilder.Select().Expand().Filter().OrderBy().MaxTop(null).Count();

    // insert special bits for e.g. custom MLE here
    routeBuilder.EnableDependencyInjection();
  });
}
```

New classes CustomODataOutputFormatter.cs and CommonExtensions.cs

```cs
public class CustomODataOutputFormatter : ODataOutputFormatter
{
  private readonly JsonSerializer serializer;
  private readonly bool isDevelopment;

  public CustomODataOutputFormatter(bool isDevelopment) 
    : base(new[] { ODataPayloadKind.Error })
  {
    this.serializer = new JsonSerializer { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() };
    this.isDevelopment = isDevelopment;

    this.SupportedMediaTypes.Add("application/json");
    this.SupportedEncodings.Add(new UTF8Encoding());
  }

  public override Task WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
  {
    if (!(context.Object is SerializableError serializableError))
    {
      return base.WriteResponseBodyAsync(context, selectedEncoding);
    }

    var error = serializableError.CreateODataError(this.isDevelopment);        
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(context.HttpContext.Response.Body))
    {
      this.serializer.Serialize(writer, error);
      return writer.FlushAsync();
    }
  }    
}

public static class CommonExtensions
{
  public const string DefaultODataErrorMessage = "A server error occurred.";

  public static ODataError CreateODataError(this SerializableError serializableError, bool isDevelopment)
  {
    // ReSharper disable once InvokeAsExtensionMethod
    var convertedError = SerializableErrorExtensions.CreateODataError(serializableError);
    var error = new ODataError();
    if (isDevelopment)
    {
      error = convertedError;
    }
    else
    {
      // Sanitise the exposed data when in release mode.
      // We do not want to give the public access to stack traces, etc!
      error.Message = DefaultODataErrorMessage;
      error.Details = new[] { new ODataErrorDetail { Message = convertedError.Message } };
    }

    return error;
  }

  public static ODataError CreateODataError(this Exception ex, bool isDevelopment)
  {
    var error = new ODataError();

    if (isDevelopment)
    {
      error.Message = ex.Message;
      error.InnerError = new ODataInnerError(ex);
    }
    else
    {
      error.Message = DefaultODataErrorMessage;
      error.Details = new[] { new ODataErrorDetail { Message = ex.Message } };
    }

    return error;
  }
}
```

Changes to the controller:

```cs
[EnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.Supported, PageSize = 2000)]
public IQueryable<DimDateAvailable> Get()
{
  return this.data.DimDateAvailable.AsQueryable();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a customization of responses, including customization of error responses try to use ODataQueryOptions instead of using

```
[EnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.Supported, PageSize = 2000)]
```

Check some samples at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options#invoking-query-options-directly

It would allow you to cache validation errors and build custom response.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this issue in the past and the only one way I got this working without having to write a middleware was like:

Try this:

```
    catch (ODataException ex)
    {
        HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;//This line is important, if not it will return 500 Internal Server Error.
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);//Just respond back the actual error which is 100% correct.
    }
```

Then the error will look like:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "http://yourendpoint.com$metadata#Edm.String",
    "value": "The property 'test' cannot be used in the $select query option."
}
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks

Comment: This seemed promising but ultimately doesn't catch errors for me when I put this inside my ASP.NET Core action method. It appears as though the error happens before the action is executed. I thought it might occur after the action is executed due to delayed evaluation of the `IQueryable`, but it appears to happen before routing.

Comment: Hi @flipdoubt you can try to use this logic within a custom middleware and then try to play with the order your middleware is invoked to see what you get.

Comment: I put this inside a custom `EnableQueryAttribute` to acheive the desired results. Details at https://stackoverflow.com/a/63176502/470.

Comment: where in the list of configuring middleware would you put this custom middleware? Between authentication and routing?

Comment: Try it out after the authentication so you prevent your custom middleware to handle logic before the auth happens.

Comment: I tried that but I'm not sure what to do that would trigger the exception to be thrown inside the middleware. If I just wrap `await next()` inside a `try/catch(ODataException)`, the error never occurs until after.

Comment: Try updating the context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest. You can inject the HttpContext to your InvokeAsync and try to do so when that exception occurs. Let me know what happens after that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218930/discussion-between-flipdoubt-and-ernest).